# Finding primes in Python (trouble with the modulus operator?)

Tags: python, primes

I need to calculate prime numbers. I got the below code from a separate thread:

```
for p in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
           break
        else:
           print p,
```

However, when I run it myself I get:

3 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 9 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 15 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 21....

Some of which are obviously not primes. I'm on a challenge of Euler's Project that requires prime calculation; after a bit of thought I got to a piece of code similar to the above, but ran into the same problem, which is when I turned to the forum and took this. I'm wondering whether there's something up with the way that the modulus operator is functioning on my machine?

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what is this trailing coma after `print p` ?

Comment: The trailing comma makes no difference..

Comment: Voting to close as a likely copy-and-paste error. The `else` is probably supposed to belong to the `for`. Move `else:` and `print p` four spaces to the left, and it works as expected.

Comment: @deceze: IMO it is premature to conclude a typo.

Comment: @deceze what you say is right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You break when you are sure that the number is composite. But if you are unsure, you print anyway.

The fix is easy, thanks to the clever Python loop construct:

```
for p in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
           break
    else:
       print p,
```

---

But *please*, stop the inner loop as soon as `i²>=p` !